# QDebug passing custom debug message type in Qt 4.7

Tags: qt, qdebug

We are building a static library that is using `qDebug` and its variants(qWarning,QCritical etc)  and custom `qDebug` message handler. Because of this every `qDebug`and its variants and its variants are redirected to our message handler. But we don't want to handle application's `qDebug` and its variants in our message handler. One work around we can do is that passing custom debug message type in the `QDebug` that we are using inside our static library and checking for this in `qMessageHandler` callback. But is this safe? Another way we thought of is creating a class that is similar to `QDebug` and overload stream insertion `<<` operator for every data type same like `QDebug` does. In Qt 5.2+ we have logging category with which easily can achieve this. But unfortunately we have to use qt 4.7 in our project. Can any one please tell whether there is any easier way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since calling [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) returns a reference to the original message handler, assuming you use Qt5, you could handle yourself all message type except the ones of type `QtDebugMsg` where you would call the previous handler.

Comment: Sorry, I think I need to change the question by qDebug I meant qDebug and all its variants like qWarning, qCritical etc. Also we are not using Qt5.2 in which we can use debug log category.

Comment: @Arjuna in Qt4 must be use http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler

Comment: @eyllanes. Thank you. We are already using it. But the issue is that we want to differentiate whether the call is from our static library or is it from outside.

Comment: @Arjuna 
okay, I understand, you want to differentiate if it comes from the library or comes from your own application(current).

Comment: @eyllansec Yes exactly